# WireCloud cannot connect to local ContextBroker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I have WireCloud and Orion ContextBroker running locally from separate Docker container. I tried to connect WireCloud and ContextBroker through NGSI source widget.

I get following error: `Error retrieving initial values`

In the NGSI source configuration, I have tried both localhost and orion container IP, both resulting in same error.

Am I missing any other configuration?

Comment: Tried to run local ngsi-proxy and added NGSI Proxy URL to the configuration of the widget. Now I get the following error: 

`Error creating subscription in the context broker server: Connection Error`

I can't seem to find any further instruction on how to setup and use local ngsi-proxy